# Push entire remote git repository to another remote

Tags: git, github, remote-branch

I've forked my project off the wrong project (I forked a fork) and I want to reset my GitHub repository to be forked off of the original.  Moving a fork in GitHub involves dropping and reforking AFAIK.  The only problem is I want to push my old remote branch refs to the new branch without making local branches because (let's say for the sake of argument) I have 100 different branches and it would take too much time to check out new local versions of each remote branch. (My local branch list is pretty lean but I leave fix branches up on GitHub usually).

Comment: I don't completely understand the issue, but have you tried adding a new remote (`git remote add $name $url`) and then running `git push --all` (or `--mirror`)?

Comment: If I do git branch -a I'll see 1 or 2 branches locally and then 100 branches that say /remotes/repoA/branchName, I want them to show up in branchB as /remotes/repoB/branchName without having to create local branches and do a push --all

Comment: I think `--mirror` is what you're looking for. Clone the repository you have on disk to a new location using the mirror flag, add the new remote to it, and push it with the mirror flag to the new remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using right `refspec` in `git push` (step 4):

1. Rename remote-tracking references `refs/remotes/origin/...` to `refs/remotes/oldfork/...` by renaming remote: `git remote rename origin oldfork`
2. Drop and re-fork the repo at GitHub
3. Re-add `origin` remote: `git remote add origin <url>`
4. Push old branches to new fork: `git push origin 'refs/remotes/oldfork/*:refs/heads/*'`
5. Remove `oldfork` remote: `git remote remove oldfork`

If you had your own tags in the original fork, please add `--tags` to the `git push` command line.